# Simplify columns using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, group, lines-of-code

I want to consolidate columns into the pictured format below using python pandas.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMxWc.png)

I've tried the groupby specific columns method, df.loc method, transpose the columns and ran into duplicating issues when trying to get the solution goal.

Comment: `melt` or `stack`